# Is there away to push the same element into 2 different arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, push

I want to push the same element into 2 different arrays without repeating myself and keeping the code dry. Is there any way of doing this with JS?

```
var arrayA = [];
var arrayB = [];
var a = "a";

arrayA.push(a)
arrayB.push(a)
```

Can I combine those 2 last lines into one? I was thinking something like:

`[arrayA, arrayB].push(a)` ? But this doesn't seem to work

Thanks

Comment: There isn't something else that is better than your two lines of code.  It can be hacked into one line, but not with something that is actually better than your two lines.  If you really want, you can just make a function that puts it into two arrays and call the function.  But, I don't see the point unless this is something you do in lots of places in your code in which case, you should put the two arrays into an object and give that object a method and let the method take care of pushing it wherever it has to be pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of an overkill, but you can wrap them both in an array, and use `Array.forEach()` to push the item to the original arrays:

```js
var arrayA = [];
var arrayB = [];
var a = "a";

[arrayA, arrayB].forEach(arr => arr.push(a));

console.log({
  arrayA,
  arrayB
});
```

Comment: Unless OP has an arbitrary amount of arrays, the original code is probably better. Also, for...of (i.e. `for (var arr of [arrayA, arrayB])`) could work if ES6 is an option.